# Array value get overwrited every time java

Tags: java, arrays, overwrite

i try to add some objects(servei) in this code and the new one allways overwrite the last one and i can't find the error :/,i have two points p and i,I use i for the array only when deleting llista[p] objects,cause i don't want null values inside my array,i added the code,when i use e,and servei cause some people said that there could be the error too.

System.out.println(llista.afegirServei(serv)); // that's what i use to add a new servei

```
public class Llistaservei {
    private int i;
    private Servei[] llista;
    private int p = 0;
    private float opinio;

    public Llistaservei(int Max_Serv) {
        llista = new Servei[Max_Serv]; 
    }

    public String AfegirServei(Servei servei) {
        if (ValidServei(servei.getNom()) == i) {
            return ("El servei ja existeix"); //if exist return that "servei" exist.
        } else { ***//finally works cleaning eclipse cache...***
                llista[p]=servei;
            p++;
            return ("El servei s'ha creat correctament");// I add a new "Servei to the array" if doesn't exist
        }
    }

    public String EliminarServei(String nom){
    if(ValidServei(nom)==-1){
        llista[i]=llista[p];    //here i use 2 pointers p,i cause i don't want null 
        llista[p]=null;         //in the middle of the array
        p--;
        return ("El servei s'ha eliminat correctament"); //if is valid 
    }                                                    //return "servei" deleted

    public int ValidServei(String nom) {
        for (i = 0; ((i < p) && (i < llista.length)); i++) {
            if (nom.equalsIgnoreCase(llista[i].getNom())) {
                return i;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The curse of the foreign language: I can't read your code and thus not guess what you  want to do. You will have to tell us.

Comment: Can you first correct your code. The use of variable i seems to be messed up.

Comment: is `p` incrementing?  I usually like to assign values in the constructor

Comment: p is incrementing,the thing is that the array is allways null,o have the value i add when go to validServei

Answer (score 4):

Since `ValidServei` returns `i` and shares `i` your method will always return a value where `i` matches it here -

```
if (ValidServei(servei.getNom())==i){
```

Instead you could write a `contains` like,

```
public boolean contains(String nom) {
    for (int i = 0; i < p && i < llista.length; i++) {
        if (nom.equalsIgnoreCase(llista[i].getNom())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And Java method names start with a lower case letter by convention. Like,

```
public String afegirServei(Servei servei) {
    if (contains(servei.getNom())) {
        return ("El servei ja existeix");
    }
    llista[p++] = servei;
    return ("El servei s'ha creat correctament");
}
```

Finally, you should probably be using a [`Set<Servei>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) collection (instead of an array) like,

```
Set<Servei> set = new HashSet<>();
set.add(servei);
```

Comment: i tried with boolean before,but it's a university project so i can't use it(teacher says that there are collateral problems or something like that),and can't use collections or even arraylist so that complicates me a bit...

Comment: finally works with the solution i edited last time,thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

I can't edit, so here is the translated code. 
This is only for the community to be able to read
your question, since you don't seem to change your code in the question.

```
public class ServiceList {
private int i;
private Service[] list;
private int p = 0;
private float opinion;

public ServiceList(int maxServer)
{
    list = new Service[maxServer];
}

public String addService(Service service){

    if(chooseService(service.getName()) == i){
        return("The service already exists");
    }
    else
    {
        list[p]=service;
        p++;
        return("The service was successfully created");
    }   

public int chooseService(String name){
    for(i=0; ((i<p) && (i<list.length)); i++){
        if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(list[i].getname())){
            return i;
        }
```

Comment: I think this would be more appropriate as an edit to the original question.

Comment: You are right, this was my first thought too. But "too long by 295 characters". Since it doesn't hurt anybody and improves the readability of the question, I think it's fine.

Comment: I was unaware of the length restriction on editing the original question. Interesting. In that case, I agree completely.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guess that, considering the lacks of some `}` and the value of `i` in `AfegirServei` is missing, you're cut your source code and put what you believe that it's necessary to understand the problem. I'm pretty sure that the problem is in the parameter `servei` when you call `public String AfegirServei(Servei servei)`. It's very possible that you're passing the wrong object or something like that. Of course, I can be sure only I see the full source code.

Comment: i use eclipse,so the lack of } isn't a problem...and the Servei code was already given and implemented,by the way the real problem is that when i add a "Servei" it's overwrites the last one every time,so i allways have 1 value inside the array insited more of one.

Comment: finally works with the solution i edited last time,thank you anyway